# How to update nameservers for my domain

Tags: dns, nameserver, cname, cloudflare

I've registered for a CloudFlare CDN and enabled it for my domain. Now CloudFlare asks me to use two specific nameservers that they assigned to my domain, e.g.

1. nameserver-address-1.com
2. nameserver-address-2.com

I'm asked to update my DNS records with these records.

The problem is that I'm not sure which records I should update/add (CNAME or A). Moreover, while trying to sort it out I noticed that it is not possible to use two nameserver addresses for my domain. Only ONE can be assigened to the domain.

These are my settings:

www.my-domain.com.  14400   IN  CNAME   nameserver-address-1.com

I'm not able to add nameserver-address-2.com for the same domain.

Is my configuration correct, and how I should use the second nameserver address as instructed by CloudFlare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to update your nameserver records through your DNS host.   If you need to modify an A record or a CNAME record, you would want to do so through your DNS host.  However, name server records are not modified with your DNS host.

Cloudflare is asking to *be* your DNS host.   You need to set the nameserver records through your domain registrar.  For example, if your domain registrar is GoDaddy, you would [follow their instructions for setting up custom nameservers](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/12317/setting-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us?locale=en).